# matrix eigenvector calculation when inverse already known?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a symmetric, real, square matrix (n by n, where n~64) who's inverse is already known. I was wondering if there is a fast method for computing the eigenvector decomposition of this matrix, since the inverse is already available ? Does already having the inverse help ? Furthermore, I only need the first p eigenvectors with largest magnitude eigenvalue, where p is much smaller than n.

I am working in a real-time low level computing environment where time and memory are constrained, and using principal component analysis for dimensionality reduction.

Thank you!

Comment: The inverse does you very little good, unfortunately. In particular it doesn't even help you do inverse iteration, since you want the large eigenvalues rather than the small ones.